# What is the HTML5 alternative to the obsolete meta http-equiv=content-language.

Tags: html, validation, content-type, multilingual

I'm finishing up an HTML5 site that has a mixture of English and Mandarin Chinese.

My validator (HTML5 Validator add-on for FF) is giving me this error:

```
error: Using the “meta” element to specify the document-wide default
language is obsolete. Consider specifying the language on the root
element instead.

At line 6, column 9: <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
```

the relevant code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

checking W3.org leads me to this page: [telling me that yes, it's obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/meta.http-equiv.content-language.html)

I must confess I don't understand how I am supposed to bring this code into compliance?

I don't know what **"specifying the language on the root element"** means, or how to do it?

Surely `<html lang="en">` doesn't suffice for `UTF-8` ?

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong line.  The meta-tag you're referring to in the link is "content-language" but the one you listed here is "content-type".

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In HTML5 you can actually define `lang` for each element. That means if you have a `div` that contains Mandarin Chinese in it, just define an attribute `lang="zh-CN"` for that div, like `<div lang="zh-CN">`.

Comment: can I define both for mixed content?

Comment: @Andrew - No you can't. The lang attribute only ever takes a single language code.

Comment: @Andrew: you’re meant to pick the primary (i.e. most commonly used) language for the page, and indicate that via the `lang` attribute on the `<html>` element, then wrap any content in a different language in an element with a `lang` attribute indicating the language.

Comment: Using meta tags to set the charset is wrong as it makes the browser parse the document using [charset guessing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charset_detection) until it stumbles upon the meta tag in which case it restarts the parsing using the correct encoding; this is a big performance issue and charset guessing is unreliable. The correct way to do it is to serve the document with the `Content-Type` header with the correct charset in it.

Answer (score 11):

See below for language and charset settings

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>title</title>
.....
```