# http-equiv="content-language" doesn't work (element.lang = "")

Tags: javascript, html, http, meta

```js
console.log("lang = " + document.documentElement.lang);
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="es">
    </head>
    <body></body>
    <html>
```

Why?

[According to specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#the-lang-and-xmllang-attributes), If neither the node nor any of the node’s ancestors, including the root element, have either attribute set, but **there is a pragma-set default language set, then that is the language of the node**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the HTML5 alternative to the obsolete meta http-equiv=content-language.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116812/what-is-the-html5-alternative-to-the-obsolete-meta-http-equiv-content-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specification says](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/document-metadata.html#statedef-http-equiv-content-language):

> This feature is non-conforming. Authors are encouraged to use the lang attribute instead.

[Another note](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-http-and-lang) says:

> The `Content-Language` value for an `http-equiv` attribute on a `meta` element should no longer be used.

As [What is the HTML5 alternative to the obsolete meta http-equiv=content-language.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116812/what-is-the-html5-alternative-to-the-obsolete-meta-http-equiv-content-language) suggests, using `lang=` instead works:

```js
console.log("lang = " + document.documentElement.lang);
```

```html
    <html lang="es">
```

If your aim is to set the language, that's a better way to do it.